# How to parse XMPP Chat History XML | Android

Tags: android, xml, xmpp, chat

I need to Parse the Chat History XML Response.
Here is XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message to="user5@192.168.1.59/Smack" from="user5@192.168.1.59">
   <result xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1">
      <body>helooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</body>
      <thread>sO678v</thread>
      <composing />
      <delay />
   </result>
</message>
```

I need to get the value of `"to"` and `"from"` from above XML.

Please suggest me, what to do now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @krislarson My question is NOT ABOUT JSON PARSING. Its about XML Parsing.

Comment: Sorry, staring at JSON waaaaaay too long... Good grief.  Let me try again: Have a look at XmlPullParser https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html  There's a nice example in the Java Docs.  Then write some code etc. etc.  Think I need a vacation.

Comment: Alright @krislarson Thanks